# Deploying Jaeger in a url different than root

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, kubernetes-ingress, jaeger

I am trying to deploy Jaeger all-in-one image in a kubernetes cluster.
Jaeger is not in the root of the url, meaning it's accessible through https://somedomain.com/xyz/jaeger

I have an ingress rule which seems to be pointing correctly to a Service which is also referencing fine the pod in a deployment (I can see all this in Rancher UI).

But somehow when I try to access, nginx is throwing a 502 Bad Gateway error.

This is how the ingress rule looks like

```
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress
  namespace: my-namespace
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
spec:
  rules:
    - host: somedomain.com
      http:
          # Jaeger
          - path: /xyz/jaeger(/|$)(.*)
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service: 
                name: jaeger
                port: 
                  number: 16868
```

Then in the pod definition I tried using the `QUERY_BASE_PATH` env var setting it to `/xyz/jaeger` but that made no difference at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was an incorrect port being specified.
`16868` instead of `16686`